# I have error while i copy laravel project from shared hosting to local

Tags: laravel-5

I want to copy laravel from shared hosting into my computer and run it from xampp server
this is my road:

1. i'm compress public_html folder from host
2. download it and extract in xampp/htacess/project_name directory
3. i was export database from server and import in local phpmyadmin
4. delete vender directory and run composer install
5. edit config/database.php with my local database information
6. edit .env file with local information
   after all i run php artisan serve and i get this error
   screenshot avilable up there
   does anybody can help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QDDK.png)

Comment: any body cant help me?